# ResourceConflictException, The function could not be updated

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have an authorizer lambda within which I need to update an environment variable which will be used for logging the user in. However when I try to run my selenium tests to simulate 16 users in parallel I get a `ResourceConfilitException, The function could not be update error`.

```
function getSalt(functionName) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (process.env[saltKey]) {
      return resolve(process.env[saltKey]);
    }

    const salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
    const lambda = new AWS.Lambda();

    let newFunctionName = functionName;

    return lambda.getFunctionConfiguration({ FunctionName: newFunctionName }, (getSaltError, data) => {
      if (getSaltError) {
        const getFunctionConfigError = new Error('Error getting function configuration');
        console.error(getFunctionConfigError);
        console.error(getSaltError);
        return reject(getSaltError);
      }

      const environmentVariables = data.Environment.Variables || {};
      environmentVariables[saltKey] = salt;

      const params = {
        FunctionName: data.FunctionName,
        Environment: {
          Variables: environmentVariables,
        },
      };

      return lambda.updateFunctionConfiguration(params, (updateError) => {
        if (updateError) {
          const saltError = new Error('Faild to update environment variables with new salt.');

          console.error(saltError);
          console.error(updateError);

          return reject(updateError);
        }

        return resolve(salt);
      });
    });
  });
}
```

This error doesn't happen when I try to simulate async calls to this lambda via a `await Promise.all(Array(n).fill().map(() => httpsCallAuthorizerLambda()))` call. so I couldn't reproduce the issue.

Comment: How about when they sign in put all the user data in a JWT? I can provide an example if needed? Also see here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_UpdateFunctionConfiguration.html, it looks like returning 409 resource already exists which means you're getting duplicate values? I dunno though I'm shooting in the dark here as I haven't come across this before.

Comment: Err and if I'm reading this right you're trying to store the salt per user in an env var? If you must do it that way store user data in the JWT and then decrypt the claims using a key from SSM and do your logic there. Once I understand your use case I'll write ya an answer!

Comment: I have a `simpe identity provider` that we use to authorize our users when our other identity providers are not functioning (which happens a lot ). so I need to store a salt for each lambda for each environment, so the first time that the lambda is called the env variable `SALT` doesn't exist and I try to set it as environment variable using the `update configuration` command @MrkFldig

Comment: Ahh OK, hmm so essentially you want to switch Identity provider depending on who's working? I shall do some research, in the normal run of things I take it you'd only update this max every few minutes rather than loads all at once? Your problem arises when you try and do lots of updates in a short space of time?

Comment: yes, it happens when I try to call the endpoint with 16 concurrent users (in our integrations tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more investigations I finally managed to reproduce the problem. The problem happens because more than one lambda function tried to set the `environment variables` at the same time during the run time which caused a `ResourceConflictException`. I solved the issue by removing the  `updateFunctionConfiguration` for setting env variables during the `run time` and changed it to set the `env variable` the `deploy time` as it was a one time job.

```
aws lambda get-function --function-name $saltLambda > /dev/null 2>&1
if [ 0 -eq $? ]; then
  echo "Lambda '$saltLambda' exists"
  sipSalt=$(aws lambda get-function-configuration --function-name $saltLambda |jq -r '.Environment.Variables.SALT')
else
  echo "Lambda '$saltLambda' does not exist"
fi

if [ -n "$sipSalt" ]; then
  sipSalt=$(openssl rand -hex 16)
fi
npx sls deploy --sipSalt $sipSalt
```